# How can i utilize/implement TFLogv

Tags: iphone, ios, testflight

I need to generate a local log file which user can send us as mail, along with TestFlight implementation.

From TestFlighApp doc,
Using TFLogv you can have your method that accepts a variable number of arguments that then passes that format and argument list to TFLog.

So, i think i can capture whatever testflighapp intend to send over its server and have it collected in local file.

So, please guide me if i am in the right direction and how i can make use of this function.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
void MyLog(NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, format);
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:arg_list];
    va_end(argList);

    // send to TestFlight
    TFLog(@"%@", message);
    // TODO: save to my log
    // { your code here }
}
```

And then call MyLog instead of TFLog.